# How to filtered list of record(groupby field) in such a way filtered list contains record from each group

Tags: django, random, django-models, django-queryset

Consider there is a list of recordsets.

id  name topic_id
1  hiii       1
2  hell      2
3  test      2
4  good    3
5  badg    4
6  byeo    4

Now I want 4 records in such a way that there is at least one record of each topic_id.

It is possible through the loop, but if by default Django ORM providing such a mechanism?

Comment: Show your topic model structure. it's definitely possible by Django.

Comment: The topic is having name(char) and info(text) field